# how to separate accepted status from 400 status in response.text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, put, http-response-codes

I'm getting two conflicting error messages from my PUT request. I'm using the Python requests module and a client.The response.text looks like this:

```
    {u'status': 400, u'errors': {u'error': u'We have identified 1 error 
    in your request:  (1) We could not download the URL'}, 
    u'reference': u'4C7EC36B:CE5D_0A40E1F1:01BB_5A822CF3_EFE35:18B1'}
    {u'status': u'accepted', u'mediaId': u'f3327905-1873-4e0d-b07c-
    4e7f88741c3b', u'_links': {u'self': {u'href': u'/v2-
    beta/media/f3327905-1873-4e0d-b07c-4e7f88741c3b'}}, u'metadata':{}}
```

The problem is that my code needs to use the mediaId and if the first 400 status weren't there, it would read it, but since I can't seem to get rid of that error, I need it to skip past it and read the response with the 'status': 'accepted' and the mediaId.

I tried iterating through it with this:

```
    for status in response:
            if 'status' is 'accepted':
                file_url = fileURL
                external_id = externalId
                media_id = response['mediaId']
                status = response['status']
                results_writer.writerow([ file_url, external_id, 
    media_id, status])
    elif 'status' > 200:
                print "blat"
```

and it only goes to the 400 status, without doing the first "if" statement.How could I change it to read the 'accepted' status response?

Answer (score 0):

`if 'status' is 'accepted':`

`elif 'status' > 200:`

The above two lines are comparing the string `'status'` with another object. The first is always False and the second is always True. You probably meant to compare the variable, i.e. `if status == 'accepted':`

(As a side note, don't use `is` to compare strings... that doesn't always do what you might think it does. Use `==` instead.)

Comment: cool. I made that change but it still doesn't do the actions in the if statement. No errors, but nothing done. Also, if I use status as a variable I get a NameError.